# how to set HttpsURLConnection method type to POST

Tags: java, http

I am writing a unit test class in Java, in that I want to set the method type POST, but it is showing me GET while debugging. Below is the code snippet I am trying. ANny help is appreciated.

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
URL url = new URL("wsURL");
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInputMethod("POST");
```

Comment: Why did you change the code in your question?  It's correct now, at least what you have showed us.  If there is some error, please post the stack trace or output.

Comment: previous was my typo, thats why editted..

Comment: _"showing me GET while debugging"_... where, exactly?

Comment: I am setting httpMethod as POST but when I am debugging & checking the object connection it shows httpMethod type as GET.

Answer (score 0):

You was using connection.**setInputMethod**("POST");
 but you should have used connection.**setRequestMethod**("POST");

 After changing setInputMethod to setRequestMethod("POST") it should work